# How many files can I upload at once to Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

We're thinking about using Firebase Hosting (which is awesome: ssl, control over redirects, easy CLI tool, etc) to host our API docs. Currently, we count 17k files generated. We did a test upload, and everything worked (pretty cool!). We're curious, is there a limit to the number of files we can deploy to Firebase Hosting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a limit on the number of files. But they zipped result (which is what actually gets uploaded) definitely has to be less than 2GB.

Comment: I'm just curious why should it definitely be less than 2GB?

Comment: The underlying Zip tool has a limit on the size it can output which is (was?) 2GB