# Uploading 100GB of data

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I intend to use Firebase "Blaze Pay as you go Plan" to upload ~350 files (.html files) with a total size of about 100GB using the hosting service. To do so I will simply copy all my files into the public folder and use `firebase deploy` CLI.

Is there any limit to how many files/size that can be uploaded?

Is there a way to avoid uploading all the files at once, and instead to do it in several steps (like 50 files at a time)?

Comment: There is no way to upload in parts. As to the maximum number of files, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450040/how-many-files-can-i-upload-at-once-to-firebase-hosting

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see, but if the maximum hosting upload is 2GB then why do they offer a 10BG upload in their Flame Plan? It doesn't make much sense...